# Validate uniqueness of attribute scoped by another attribute presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, validates-uniqueness-of

If I need to validate uniqueness of cat name scoped by owner so that no owner can have many cats with same name I can use that:

`validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :owner_id`

But how can I validate the uniqueness scoped by that the cat has owner or not?

So that all cats that have an owner, have unique names.

And all cats that don't have an owner, have unique names.

So it's something like scoped by `scope: self.owner.present?`.

Can I do so with validations helpers without using custom validation method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a `conditions` clause to your uniqueness validation. See [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of), which gives this example:

```rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, conditions: -> { where.not(status: 'archived') }
end
```

So if you wanted to ensure uniqueness for all cats with no owner, you would write

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :name, conditions: -> { where(owner_id: nil) }
```

Or if you wanted to ensure that all cats with owners are uniquely named, regardless of who their owner is:

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :name, conditions: -> { where.not(owner_id: nil) }
```

If you only want to do one or the other, that'd work. However, if you want to do both, you'd find that both conditions are checked - and effectively, you're back with a uniqueness constraint that checks against the whole table, but in two queries instead of one.

So, if we **do** want both checks, we need to make sure that only one of them gets checked, which we can do with `if`/`unless` modifiers:

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :name, conditions: -> { where(owner_id: nil) },
    if: -> { owner_id.nil? }
validates_uniqueness_of :name, conditions: -> { where.not(owner_id: nil) },
    unless: -> { owner_id.nil? }
```

So now, if your cat has an owner ID, the validation that checks uniqueness within the scope of all records with an owner ID will run. But if it doesn't have an owner ID, the other validation will kick in instead.

It means a few more hoops to jump through, but should meet your need.

Comment: That's what I don't actually need, that will validate uniqueness if cat doesn't have an owner.

What I need cats with owners have their unique names, cats without owners have their unique names.

Comment: @AhmedSalah I get you – I'll edit the answer.